# CSS encender y apagar, pero sin transición

Tags: css, animación

¿Cómo puedo hacer que un o un circulo dibujado con css se vea y oculte pero sin el efecto suavizado que da el hacerlo con animation?

Que sea como una luz se ve o no se ve y parpadea constantemente.

No quiero que se encienda suavemente y se apague suavemente. Necesito que aparezca bruscamente en 3 posiciones.

A continuación, mi código:

```css
.triangulo {
     width: 0; 
     height: 0; 
     position: relative;
     left: 85px;
     /*bottom: 15px;*/
     border-left: 15px solid transparent;
     border-right: 15px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 25px solid #b10c0c;

    animation-duration: 3s;
   animation-name: slidein;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     
}

@keyframes slidein {
 
   
   0%{border-bottom: 25px solid #b10c0c; left: 85px;}
   1%{border-bottom: 25px solid transparent; left: 85px;}
   30%{border-bottom: 25px solid #b10c0c; left: 200px;}
   31%{border-bottom: 25px solid transparent; left: 200px;}
   50%{border-bottom: 25px solid #b10c0c; left: 320px;}
   51%{border-bottom: 25px solid transparent; left: 320px;}
 
}
```

```html
<div class="triangulo">
  
 </div>
```

Comment: Sube tu código para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Listo Ya subí el código, lo único que subí el de un triangulo, pero al caso es el mismo

Comment: @etxu00 gracias, era lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No entiendo de todo tu pregunta, pero me imagino que lo que quieres es que la animación no sea lineal. Si es el caso prueba con la instrucción

```
animation-timing-function: step-start
```

Esta instrucción corta los incrementos matemáticos, es decir 1 al 10 elimina el 2, 3, ... en el lapso de tiempo.

Comment: Espero y te funcione, suerte.

Comment: Era lo que necesitaba, Muchas Gracias.